# Use class as template or parameter?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I would like a class dict so that I can manage local-unique classes (per class dict instance).

```
class A { }

class ClassDict {
    kvp: { [k:string]: any }; // not sure if there is better way
}

b = new ClassDict()
```

I tried to implement as following but it seems redundant:

```
// call as b.add<A>(new A())
public add<T>(t: T): T {
  this.kvp[t.name] = t;
  return t;
}

// call as b.get<A>(A)
public get<T>(t: any): T {
  return this.kvp[t.name] as any as T;
}
```

If I just use class in template, I cannot call `.name` to get the key.

If I just use class as parameter, I cannot declare return type.

I hope I can call like this:

```
// creates an object of A
// since param is instance of A, it is supposed to know it
b.add(new A())

// updates an object of A
// same as add
b.update(new A())

// returns an object of A
b.get(A);
// or
b.get<A>()

// removes an object of A, this might be easier as it returns void
b.remove(A)
// or
b.remove<A>()
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `t.name` meant to be? It's not defined anywhere in the code you've shown

Comment: @MoreThanTom It is built-in field. Every constructor can call it to get the name of the class. You can try in console `class A{}; A.name`. In my example, it will return `'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

We give `class A` as `new()=>A`. So you have to give `get<T>(t: new()=>T)`

Here is how its completely done in typescript:

```
class A {
}

class ClassDict {
    kvp: { [k: string]: any } = {};

    public add<T>(t: T){
        this.kvp[t.constructor.name] = t;
    }
    public get<T>(t: new()=>T) {
        return this.kvp[t.name] as T;
    }
    public update<T>(t:T) {
        this.kvp[t.constructor.name] = t;
    }
    public remove<T>(t: new()=>T) {
        this.kvp[t.name] = undefined;
    }
}
let b = new ClassDict()

b.add<A>(new A())
let d = b.get(A); // typeof d is A
b.update(new A())
b.remove(A)
```

You can see the live working at [Typescript Playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ClassDict%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20kvp%3A%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20add%3CT%3E(t%3A%20T)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.kvp%5Bt.constructor.name%5D%20%3D%20t%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%3CT%3E(t%3A%20new()%3D%3ET)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.kvp%5Bt.name%5D%20as%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20update%3CT%3E(t%3AT)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.kvp%5Bt.constructor.name%5D%20%3D%20t%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20remove%3CT%3E(t%3A%20new()%3D%3ET)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.kvp%5Bt.name%5D%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20ClassDict()%0A%0Ab.add%3CA%3E(new%20A())%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20b.get(A)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20d%20is%20A%0Ab.update(new%20A())%0Ab.remove(A)%0A). Post comments in case of further need.

**Update:**

The `.name` property of function came with ES6. So in order to get this thing known to typescript you must include the latest libraries in configuration:

```
tsc test.ts --lib 'dom','es2018'
```

When using `--lib` you have to specify all the libraries typescript should use, including the default which it was using implicitly need to be mentioned here explicitly.

Comment: `semantic error TS2339 Property 'name' does not exist on type 'new () => T'`

Comment: at which line are you getting this error? What is the ts version you are using. There seems no error in the playground link shared above.

Comment: implementation of `get`

Comment: Which version of ts you are using? Did you check the above link? There seems no error.

Comment: `typescript` is `3.1.2`. I am using `vscode` and `npm`. I used `tsc` to compile and got the error.

Comment: then you need to cross check everything. Whether the new code is saved and you are running command at right location. As you are running latest ts version, It is same as playground link above. There is no error in playground for above code.

Comment: I ran `npm i -g typescript`, pasted you entire code to a `test.ts` file, ran `tsc test.ts` and also got error.

Comment: Hi! @MoYummy did you get chance to check the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

I changed API that `add` only supports constructor. (`update` and `remove` is omitted as they are identical)

```
type ComponentConstructor<C extends IComponent> = new (e: IEntity) => C;

class Entity implements IEntity {
    protected _components: { [k: string]: IComponent };

    public AddComponent<C extends IComponent>(ctor: ComponentConstructor<C>): C {
      const k = (ctor as any).name;
      if (this._components[k] === undefined) {
        const c = new ctor(this);
        this._components[k] = c;
      } else {
        console.warn(k + ' already exists.');
      }
      return this._components[k] as C;
    }

    public GetComponent<C extends IComponent>(ctor: ComponentConstructor<C>): C {
      const k = (ctor as any).name;
      return this._components[k] as C;
    }
}

// user case
class MyE extends ecs.Entity { }
class MyC extends ecs.Component { }

const e = new MyE();
const c = e.AddComponent(MyC);
e.GetComponent(MyC);
```

Comment: using `any` is not recommended in `typescript`. You are just bypassing it. Instead use javascript directly.